Getting useful Transaction data from database without "VIEW SERVER STATE"
I have a group of developers who want to collect data on wait times and catch blocking events.
I'm trying to avoid "VIEW SERVER STATE" which is needed for access to DMV  (Dynamic Management Views) as well as TRUSTWORTHY
The last time a question like this has been answered on SOF was 7 years ago, have we not found any better ideas?
I want to return data from one user database not [master], most of what I have found rely on sys.dm_exec_requests, sys.dm_exec_sessions which need "VIEW SERVER STATE" or setting the database to TRUSTWORTHY

An XEvents trace writing to a file might be a good option, it only requires ALTER EVENT SESSION permissions, and you can parse the files using normal XML methods.
